# Regular Expression to get aggregates of a formula

Tags: c#, regex

For some calculation reasons, I have to take apart the aggregates of a formula. With aggregates, I mean "SUM", "AVG", "COUNT"...

The formula has different data that goes between brackets. Could be something like this:

```
([D23] +  SUM([D24]) + [D25]) + AVG([D28])[D47][D80] - [D75]
```

As you can see, the format of an aggregate is "AGREGATE([DATA])". Those aggregates can be SUM, AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN... My goal is to get a regular expression that, with this formula, could have this output:

```
SUM([D24]) //One match
AVG([D28]) //Another match
```

I need to match the aggregates and the data that they reference. Maybe this is an easy pattern to find, but I'm new to RegEx, and I haven't been able to find it. I have tried some things, the closest that I have gotten is this pattern:

```
(SUM|AVG|COUNT|MAX|MIN)(\([^)(]*\))
```

that does what I want in terms of matches(the matches are correct, it seems), but it captures the match in two grups, like

```
SUM //One group
([D24]) //Another group
```

But, for my purposes, I need to capture everything in one group. Any hint for that would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it as non capturing groups, so that it won't capture anything.

```
(?:SUM|AVG|COUNT|MAX|MIN)(?:\([^)(]*\))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rS3aG4/4)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about non capturing groups. With that I have gotten what I wanted to achieve, something like `((?:SUM|AVG|COUNT|MAX|MIN|PRI|ULT)(?:\(\[D[0-9]+\]\)))`, so I can capture all of it in one group.
Marked as the answer.